# Can't add the widget to the home screen - App isn't installed

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to create my first widget.
I run the app through eclipse, and it launches fine.
But when I try to add the widget from the widgets menu to the home screen I get a toast that says:

> App isn't installed

When I look at the logcat I see this error:

> 05-15 18:35:10.533: E/Launcher(851): Error: appWidgetId (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID) was not returned from the \widget configuration activity.

I don't have a configuration activity at all, and as far as I understood from the developer's site, it's not a must.

Comment: show your appwidget-provider

Comment: Have you defined the id to your appwidget-provider ?

Comment: Sorry, I had a stupid mistake, there was a reference to the configuration class in the provider, that I didn't notice. Thank anyway!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID` in result intent like this:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mWidgetId));
```