# Preview image size for Android widget

Tags: android, widget

I am tyring to add a widget to my Android app, but I can't figure out how to size the preview icon. The (outdated) docs says that I should use the Widget Preview in the emulator, but there is no such app since at least API 25.
Here's my appwidget-provider xml:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="272dp"
android:minHeight="56dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="840000000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:initialLayout="@layout/mtc_appwidget"
android:configure="com.mygreatapp.MtcAppWidgetProvider"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
```

I tried with different sizes, the last on I did was 40x40, but whenever I drag the widget to the home screen, the process crashes and the widget is never added to the home screen.
This is what I find in Logcat:

```
2020-08-05 09:02:10.461 2312-2312/? E/Launcher: Error: appWidgetId (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID) was not returned from the widget configuration activity.
```

I am lost...

Comment: Nobody here who knows the answer to this question??

Comment: apparently an extremely difficult question that not even the best top notch experts can answer. VERY disappointing indeed.

Comment: have you tried googling the error message once? This is the first hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569474/cant-add-the-widget-to-the-home-screen-app-isnt-installed

Comment: I think this problem is not with image, error is telling there is some ID issue, I am sure you haven't `setResult` with ID  and key `AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID`, while creating it.

Comment: This was answered here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574860/android-widget-previewimage-size